# É possivel usar "alias" (as) no "Model.create()"?

Tags: javascript, sequelize-js

Quando uso `findAll()` consigo renomear (alias) as colunas da seguinte forma:

```
const response = await Cidades.findAll({
  attributes: [
    ['nomeCidade', 'nome']
  ]
});
```

Então a coluna nomeCidaded irá ter a chave apenas como `nome`:

```
console.log(response); // { nome: "São Paulo" }
```

A minha dúvida é se poderia fazer o mesmo com `Model.create()`. O retorno hoje é esse:

```
const response = await Cidades.create({
   nomeCidade: "São Paulo", //nome da coluna no banco de dados
   UF: "SP"
})

console.log(response) //{ nomeCidade: "São Paulo", UF: "SP" }
```

Comment: Espero que minha edição lhe dê uma ideia de como limitar a pergunta ao que é importante, havia muita coisa irrelevante na dúvida, esse é o segundo maior problema das perguntas novas no site. A pergunta tem um problema especifico e elas precisam ser focadas no especifico, sempre tento orientar para melhorarem nisso.

Comment: Em futuras perguntas que vier a fazer no site é importante sempre adicionar um [mcve], com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva, focando no problema especifico. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, tentarei executa-las nas próximas duvidas!

Answer (score -2):

Creio que não, o método *create* pode receber um *options.returning* como um array das colunas que devem ser retornadas (isso se você estiver usando o Postgres). Porém, esse array de returning não aceita um array de arrays (contendo o alias) como o findAll.